# EF Code first adds it's own FK next to the one I defined

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have 2 classes, my applicationuser which extends from Identity 2.0, and my own object. I've defined my own Foreign keys however when scaffolding a db migration EF adds 4 FK's instead of 2.

MaterialsList:

```
public class MaterialsList
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public Customer Client { get; set; }
    public MaterialsListStatus Status { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }


    public String CreatedByGuid { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CreatedByGuid")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser CreatedBy { get; set; }


    public String AssignedToGuid { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AssignedToGuid")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser AssignedTo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MaterialsRow> Rows { get; set; }
}
```

ApplicationUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MaterialsList> CreatedMaterialsLists { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MaterialsList> AssignedMaterialsLists { get; set; }
}
```

Resulting migration:

```
public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.MaterialsLists",
            c => new
                {
                    Guid = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    Status = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Date = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    CreatedByGuid = c.String(maxLength: 128),
                    AssignedToGuid = c.String(maxLength: 128),
                    ApplicationUser_Id = c.String(maxLength: 128), // I Want to use the 2 properties above instead of these
                    ApplicationUser_Id1 = c.String(maxLength: 128),
                    Client_CustomerGuid = c.Guid(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Guid)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.ApplicationUser_Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.ApplicationUser_Id1)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.AssignedToGuid)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Customers", t => t.Client_CustomerGuid)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.CreatedByGuid)
            .Index(t => t.CreatedByGuid)
            .Index(t => t.AssignedToGuid)
            .Index(t => t.ApplicationUser_Id)
            .Index(t => t.ApplicationUser_Id1)
            .Index(t => t.Client_CustomerGuid);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.MaterialsRows",
            c => new
                {
                    Guid = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    Quantity = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Product_ProductGuid = c.Guid(),
                    MaterialsList_Guid = c.Guid(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Guid)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Products", t => t.Product_ProductGuid)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.MaterialsLists", t => t.MaterialsList_Guid)
            .Index(t => t.Product_ProductGuid)
            .Index(t => t.MaterialsList_Guid);

    }
```

Does anybody have a solution for this preferably with data annotations? I'm trying to resort to the Fluent api only when there are no other options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by adding the `InverseProperty` annotation on each of the lists, as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#Relationships). Essentially, Entity Framework isn't able to determine automatically which Foreign Key each list on the `ApplicationUser`
applies to.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("CreatedBy")]
    public virtual ICollection<MaterialsList> CreatedMaterialsLists { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("AssignedTo")]
    public virtual ICollection<MaterialsList> AssignedMaterialsLists { get; set; }
}
```